# SQL Query trouble

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to write an SQL query to retrieve all of a users pending events, however it is difficult with how my tables are structured.

My tables are as follows :

```
event {
event_id
name
group_id}

Pending {
GroupID
UserID
}

Users{
Username
UserID
}
```

Ever user is identified by a UserID, and every group by a GroupID. Events have in them a GroupID which points to a list of users. I need to retrieve all pending events for a certain user, so :

```
SELECT * FROM event
WHERE event.group_id = (SELECT GroupID FROM Pending)
```

But how do I then link this so only the Pending events for a user with a certain UserID are returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select e.* from event e
inner join pending p on
e.group_id = p.GroupID
inner join Users u
on p.UserID = u.UserID
where u.UserID = 123
```

actually you can skip the join with the Users-table if you already have the UserID:

```
select e.* from event e
inner join pending p on
e.group_id = p.GroupID
where p.UserID = 123
```

The typical way to write this is using `inner join`. Traditionally it has been better performing than sub selects, but modern DBMS:s optimize them into the same query. If you really want to write with a sub select you type like this

```
SELECT * FROM event
WHERE event.group_id in (SELECT GroupID FROM Pending WHERE UserID = 123)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and especially for teaching me how you got to it, very helpful +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the JOIN clause to link the tables together rather than using the WHERE clause to filter

```
SELECT u.username, 
       e.name 
FROM   users u 
       INNER JOIN pending p 
         ON u.userid = p.userid 
       INNER JOIN event e 
         ON p.groupid = e.groupid 
WHERE 
     u.UserID = SomeID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  event.event_id
FROM event
    LEFT JOIN Pending ON event.group_id = Pending.GroupID
    LEFT JOIN Users USING (UserID)
WHERE Users.Username = 'foobar'
```

`USING()` can be utilized when columns on both sides of selection have the same name. It makes for easier reading. That is one of main reason why i would recommend to have same name for same data throughout the database. For example, if you `Documents` table and primary key `document_id`, then in all the other tables, where you are referencing the ID of a document, you use the same name for the column.

To learn more about JOINs : in [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) or [postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-join.html) read the links. And for visual representation of what each join does: [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Also you should get some book about your preferred RDBMS and learn all the basics, then you can expand your knowledge by reading [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book. Or you could just carefully look through [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back), made by book's author.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM event E,
              pending P,
              Users U
         WHERE E.group_id = P.GroupID
           AND P.UserID = U.UserID
           AND U.UserID = (Some XYZ id)
```

XYZ should be some Integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
select e.*, u.* from pending as p, users as u, event as e
WHERE
p.group_id = e.group_id
AND p.user_id = u.userID
```